# adding up sums of multiple variables in php

Tags: php, foreach, sum

ok

so I have been stuck on this problem for a while and I'm sure there is a more elegant way of doing it.

I have 3 columns in a database -

Stand1 | Stand2 | Stand3

each column will either have a stand number (i.e D30) or 'Not Assigned'

What I need to do is count how many stands have been assigned to that customer.

For example :

D30 | not assigned | not assigned would = 1

D30 | B30 | E30 = 3

The code I have so far is

```
if ($row["stand1"] == 'Not Assigned') {
    $stand1 = '0';
}  
else {
    $stand1 = '1';
}

if ($row["stand2"] == 'Not Assigned') {
    $stand2 = '0';
}  
else {
    $stand2 = '1';
}

if ($row["stand3"] == 'Not Assigned') {
    $stand3 = '0';
}  
else {
    $stand3 = '1';
}
```

I then thought I could try and count how many stand were assigned :

```
$standcount = $stand1 + $stand2 + $stand3
```

But when I print this out (everything else is in an array so loops through every customer) all I get is the total 3 for every customer.

I tried saving the data into an array like:

```
$standcount = array($stand1, $stand2, $stand3);
```

But I get the same result. I thought a foreach loop may work but not sure how to do it.

Comment: Do you need to assign a value for each variable (`$stand1`,`$stand2`,`$stand3`), or could you just use `if($row['stand1'] != 'Not Assigned'){ $standcount ++; }` (or some variant)?

Comment: Yes you are right, add all this in foreach loop.

Comment: `not assigned` and `Not Assigned` are __different__ strings

Comment: Something like this?:

$standcount = 0;
// stand number...
for($s=1;$s<=3;$s++) {
    if(isset($row['stand'.$s]) && $row['stand'.$s] !== 'Not Assigned'){
        $standcount++;
    } 
}
echo 'Stand count: '.$standcount;

Comment: That just keeps resulting in 3 for every customer

Comment: well, then, are you sure that the value for not assigned value is "Not Assigned"? What is the output of var_dump($row); ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to:

1. Set the columns' default value to `NULL`, so that if no value is provided in an entry you'll have a `null` value instead of a string (that can contains different letters, as in your case). After that you can simply perform the `isset()` check against each value.
2. Use a function to avoid code repetition (the main source of errors), something like:

   ```
   function check($value) {
       return (isset($value)) ? 1 : 0;
   }
   $stand_1 = check($row["stand1"]);
   $stand_2 = check($row["stand2"]);
   $stand_3 = check($row["stand3"]);
   ```

If you instead want to use a string as "Not Assigned" or "NA", you can perform a case-insensitive check with [`strcasecmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) between the strings in case, for any reason, a value contains an extra space or a lower-case letter. 
In this case the check function would be:

```
function check($str) {
    return (strcasecmp($str, "NA") == 0) ? 0 : 1;
}
$stand_1 = check($row["stand1"]);
$stand_2 = check($row["stand2"]);
$stand_3 = check($row["stand3"]);
```